# Fetch Location And Update Through API In Background Mode

Tags: ios, swift

I am using **Background Mode** and `func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) { }` to fetch location. Using `locationManager.distanceFilter = 10`. I guess it's fetching the location in background mode in every 10 meters. But I need to fetch in every 10 minutes and upload through POST API. For that i am using `Timer`, but timer is working perfectly in foreground mode but not working in the background mode.

**Update -->**

I am using `BGAppRefreshTask` to call API in Background. Now I am able to call API in background, also when the app is terminated. But Unable to fetch location in `BGAppRefreshTask`. Have implemented RefreshTask in `AppDelegate`.

Tried with `CLLocationManagerDelegate`. That also not worked in AppDelegate.
Please tell me the way to get location  There.

**In AppDelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`**

```
BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: "have used identifier",
                                        using: nil) { (task) in
            self.handleBGTask(task: task as! BGAppRefreshTask)
 }
```

**handleBGTask in AppDelegate**

```
func handleBGTask(task: BGAppRefreshTask) {
    task.expirationHandler = {
        task.setTaskCompleted(success: false)
    }
    var locManager = CLLocationManager()
    locManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
    print("at handleBGTask")
    if let coordinate = locManager.location?.coordinate {
        print("at handleBGTask", coordinate.longitude)
        self.utility.trackingWebservice(coordinate.latitude,coordinate.longitude,"test background"){ result in
            task.setTaskCompleted(success: true)
        }
    } else {
        print("at handleBGTask not received location")
        self.utility.trackingWebservice(dummytLat,dummyLong,"test background by dummy"){ result in
            task.setTaskCompleted(success: true)
        }
    }
    scheduleBackgroundUpdate()
}
```

**`scheduleBackgroundUpdate()`**

```
func scheduleBackgroundUpdate() {
    let bgTask = BGAppRefreshTaskRequest(identifier: "used same identifier")
    bgTask.earliestBeginDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 600)
    do {
      try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(bgTask)
    } catch {
      print("Unable to submit task: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

**In SceneDelegate**

```
func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
    (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).scheduleBackgroundUpdate()
}
```

Comment: Please scan [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+user+location+background).

Comment: In summary, you will need to keep track of the time that you last updated your server and when you get an update in `didUpdateLocations`, check if it has been 10 minutes - If so, update your server and the time you last updated your server and so on.

Comment: You can’t use Timer in the background

Answer (score -1):

There are a few reasons why a timer might not be working in background mode. One possibility is that the app is being suspended by the system. When an app is suspended, its timers are stopped. To prevent the app from being suspended, you can request a background task.

Another possibility is that the timer is being deallocated. Timers are automatically deallocated when they are no longer needed. To prevent the timer from being deallocated, you need to keep a strong reference to it.

Here is an example of how to use a timer in background mode:

```
var timer: Timer!
        
// Create a timer to fetch location in every 10 minutes.

timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 60 * 10, target: self, selector: #selector(fetchLocation), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

// Keep a strong reference to the timer.
self.timer = timer

       
// Request a background task to prevent the app from being suspended.
UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: nil)
```

Let me know how it works.

Comment: `beginBackgroundTask` only gives you about 30 seconds. This is not at all an appropriate solution for the OP's issue.

Comment: It's not working. 